# What is the proper way to provide social media authentication: in login or register form?

Tags: forms, login, registration, authentication

We provided standard login/registration forms for providing email and password, but I'd also like to allow user use my website after oAuth authentication.

Should they be able to *register* or *login* via oAuth?

Where's the right place to inform user about possibility of use *FB*, *G+* or *LinkedIn*. In login or register form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using oAuth for logging in with social media is normally used in two separate ways.

1. An option to create an account with an existing social media account so user normally don't have to go through the tedious process of filling out forms and authenticating email addresses.
2. An option to link their [your-web-application-name]account with one or several social media accounts. That way, when they enter the website and they are already logged in to, let's say Facebook, they're automatically log in to your web application.

In case of case 1, I would suggest only inform the user at registration since it's of no use to existing members.

In case of case 2, I would suggest both. Display it beneath the log in form and at the end of a registration form.

Comment: And how do you suggest to handle cases when user has already an account and choose register via FB? Should he be informed about that or just display him his data?

Comment: @squixy will the user register a totally new account like in case 1 or will there be a link between the existing account and facebook? I don't know if you can detect when they're creating a new account if they've used a different email address for FB than they did for creating the account on your website. If you can and by registering via FB they make a new account, warn them they'll make an actual second account. Otherwise, if they're creating a link between the account, tell them you're creating the link and give them the option to learn more about it's benefits.